# FP-precision related "Debug Assertion Failed!" (I have no idea why this is happening)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, precision

Ok, so I decided to do a WinAPI app that draws modular multiplication on a circle, and if the multiplier is between 0 and 0.1 (boundaries not included) it crashes. When debugging, an error message box pops up, saying "Debug Assertion Failed!" and "Press Retry to debug the application".

(Since I have like 1 rep-point, I can't post images, but [this is the error message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tBpW.png))

When I click Retry, it breaks the execution always at an `if else` statement, showing no useful information whatsoever. What is evaluated in the `if else` is none of the matter, but it's supposed to convert a `FLOAT` type number into a `CHAR *`, then convert the `CHAR *` into a `WCHAR *`. This is part of the code that (apparently) fails:

```
if (useFloat == FALSE)
    _gcvt_s(buff, 7, (multiplier / 100.0f), 4); // multiplier is type size_t (ull)
else                                            // This is where the breakpoint is set.
    _gcvt_s(buff, 7, fMultiplier, 4);           // fMultiplier is type FLOAT

mbstowcs_s(NULL, text, 7, buff, 7);
```

The execution breaks at that point, but since it may be something with the drawing itself, I'm including the loop which draws the modular multiplication on the circle (although it seems fine to me):

```
if (useFloat == FALSE)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
            D2D1::Point2F(
                ellipse.radiusX * cosf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f) + ellipse.point.x,
                ellipse.radiusY * -sinf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f) + ellipse.point.y),
            D2D1::Point2F(
                ellipse.radiusX * cosf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f * (multiplier / 100.0f)) + ellipse.point.x,
                ellipse.radiusY * -sinf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f * (multiplier / 100.0f)) + ellipse.point.y),
            pBrushLine);
    }
else
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
            D2D1::Point2F(
                ellipse.radiusX * cosf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f) + ellipse.point.x,
                ellipse.radiusY * -sinf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f) + ellipse.point.y),
            D2D1::Point2F(
                ellipse.radiusX * cosf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f * fMultiplier) + ellipse.point.x,
                ellipse.radiusY * -sinf(i * (float)M_PI / 180.0f * fMultiplier) + ellipse.point.y),
            pBrushLine);
    }
```

So yeah, I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, I read tons of threads on MSDN, SO and Reddit, and I still have not a single clue of why this may be happening.

Comment: It is an entirely normal assert that you get from the Debug version of the C runtime library.  You have this file on your machine, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\convert\cvt.cpp is a typical location.  Line #121 checks if the buffer you pass is large enough to store the result.  You need more than 7 to avoid trouble with exponential notation, minimum for 4 digits is 13.

Comment: Oh, that really helped. I was trying to find cvt.cpp based on the location shown in the error message, but I couldn't. Now reading that file (which has comments and is really nice to see) I sort of understand what is going on. Thanks, @HansPassant !